# PythonのpulpプログラムのWelcomeメッセージを出力しない方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python

(参考)2010年度 京都大・文系数学第2問 問題と解答
https://www.densu.jp/kyoto/10kyotolpass.pdf#page=2
https://www.densu.jp/kyoto/10kyotolpass.pdf#page=7

```
import pulp
x = pulp.LpVariable("x",0,10,"Continuous")
y = pulp.LpVariable("y",0,10,"Continuous")
# problem = pulp.LpProblem("test",pulp.LpMaximize)
problem = pulp.LpProblem("test",pulp.LpMinimize)
problem += 2*x + y
problem += 4*x+y <= 9
problem += x+2*y >= 4
problem += 2*x-3*y >= -6
problem.solve()
print(x.value(),y.value(),2*x.value() + y.value())
#
#Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
#Version: 2.9.0 
#Build Date: Feb 12 2015 
# (途中省略)
#0.0 2.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
problem.solve()
```

を

```
problem.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg = False))
```

とすれば、答だけを出力できますが、それ以外のメッセージは Welcome を含めてすべて省略されます。